# Check the current max pool size of IIS and current number of used connections from the pool

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have modified my web.config file to look like this:

```
<add name="Connection String" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.4.28;Initial Catalog=catalogname;User ID=admin;Password=...;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=10000;Pooling=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

However, from time to time our IIS stops working saying there are no more available connections to get from the pool.

I'm not sure it's taking the value I've set in the config file (10000) or if it's using a lower value. Also, I would like to monitor, during the execution of our system the current number of used connections.

Comment: IIS pool size as far as I know  is referred to the Application Pool where as your connection string is referred to SQL server connection pool

Comment: I understand this is the size of the pool of SQL Connections, yes.

Comment: In any case if you are handling sql connections correctly on your program, meaning you are closing them after each use, or even better use using statement, you wont end in having issues with max pool size

Comment: I know, but I want to add to my monitoring system a number displaying the current used connections from the pool. Is this possible? Also, is it possible to know the MAX POOL SIZE used?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175863(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score -4):

in my case i deny RDP in Azure and show me the error max pool, after allow RDP in Azure everything is ok.